# MPMoviePlayerController not behaving properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using MPMoviePlayerController to play a small video as an intro video of my app. I have used the following code and this works fine. But the video keeps on playing. end and restarts again. And even when i click on the done button it does not removes the superview. I also want my status bar to be visible and i kept it translucent still no result. I searched on google and stack overflow but still no help. Any help would be much appreciable.

I have called `[self playMovie]` method in `viewDidAppear`

```
-(void)playMovie
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"avc_intro" ofType:@"mp4"]];
moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer];
         name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                          object:moviePlayer];

moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
MPMoviePlayerController *videoplayer = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:videoplayer];

if ([videoplayer
     respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
{
    [videoplayer.view removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use [this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerViewController)
The MPMoviePlayerController is formally deprecated in iOS 9.

Answer (score 2):

call `[self playMovie]` from `viewDidload` because `viewDidAppear` called again when you remove `MPMoviePlayerController` so it will again start.

**Update :**

You should present `MPMusicPlayerController` instead of add it's view to super view and dissmiss it on completions

Hope this will help :)

Comment: if i call it in viewDidLoad it does not play

Comment: Thanx buddy :) @Lion

Answer (score 0):

use AVPlayerViewController and my code is give below,

objective-C code:
declare `AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;`

```
    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
    playerViewController.view.frame = videoView.bounds;
    [playerViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)];
    playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:viewModel.videoUrl]];
    [videoView addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [playerViewController.player play];
    playerViewController.player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
```

Don't Forget the Frameworks are given below,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

swift Code:

```
        let type : String! = "mp4"
        let targetURL : String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Official Apple MacBook Air Video   YouTube", ofType: "mp4")

        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:targetURL!)


        let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()

        playerController.player = player
        self.addChildViewController(playerController)
        self.playView.addSubview(playerController.view)
        playerController.view.frame = playView.bounds

        player.play()
```

Don't Forget the Frameworks are given below,

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
```

its working for me and hope its helpful